# How to get the type of object reference of instance?

Tags: java, types, classname, object-reference

*Given* an **interface**, an **abstract class** and a **concrete class**

```
interface Interface {
}

abstract class AbstractClass {
}

class C extends AbstractClass implements Interface {
}
```

I instantiate two instances of my concrete class `C` like so

```
Interface a = new C();

AbstractClass b = new C();

System.out.println(getObjectReferenceName(a));// return some.package.Interface

System.out.println(getObjectReferenceName(b));// return some.package.AbstractClass
```

/*
it return the class name of Object refernce
*/

```
String getObjectReferenceName(Object o){
    // todo
    return "class name";
}
```

How can I get the class name of the reference type?

That is -

a's object reference is **some.package.Interface**.

b's object reference is **some.package.AbstractClass**.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` fields, method parameters, local variables, ...?

Comment: a and b are reference variables.
You can use **instanceof** operator to check the reference type.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma OP wants the declared type of the variable, not the run time type.

Comment: Note that you keep referring to 'name' when what you actually seem to want is the 'type'.  Please refer to it as 'type' so that people do not get confused!

Comment: Your `AbstractClass` doesn't implement your `Interface`, is that deliberate?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Type of reference variables are already given(Declared) while instantiation.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma OP seems to want them at run time.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but that you can't determine until you are not using some overridden methods.
This questions was asking (My assumption) the type of reference variable that he can get using **instanceof** operator. :)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma (You can get it if it's a `Field`.) I'm basing my assumptions on OP's expected output. `a's object reference is some.package.Interface.`

Answer (score 3):

To get the name try

```
System.out.println(a.getClass().getInterfaces()[0]);
System.out.println(b.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

**Output:**

```
interface testPackage.InterfaceClass
class testPackage.AbstractClass
```

If you want to check if an object **is an instance of** a class, try `instanceof`.

**Edit:**

If you want to get the type the variables were declared with, you can use reflection. This works if these are fields, in other words, if they are declared as class fields, no local variables.

```
System.out.println(Test.class.getDeclaredField("a").getType()); // Test is the name of the main' method class
System.out.println(Test.class.getDeclaredField("b").getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

**a.getClass().getInterfaces()** gives you Array that contain object of Class class that represent all interfaces implemented by class of object a.

i.e. a.getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getName() gives you ***InterfaceClass***

**b.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()** gives you ***AbstractClass***

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a stupid answer but

```
// right here
//  |
//  v

Interface a = new C();
```

Also you've added a hypothetical method that returns the name of the reference type but

```
static String getReferenceType(Object o) {

    // the reality is o is always Object
    return Object.class.getName();
}
```

There's not really a situation where you need to do some program logic based on the type of a reference because you *always* know the type of the reference. It's in your own declaration. The situation where you need to call a method or instanceof operator is when you have it the other way: when you don't know the *actual* type of the object.

Comment: @SSaMKJ You misunderstand. You know `a` is an `Interface` reference because your declaration says `Interface a`. You don't need to call a method to find that out. It's in the declaration.

Comment: Oh... sorry. it returns java.lang.Object

Comment: I need this program logic. Cuz, I am making a class with reflection constructor. It is possible same parameter length but different type of constructors with implements and extends. Anyway thank you for consideration and reply.

Comment: You don't need anything special to get a constructor with specific parameters. There is a method for that: [Class#getConstructor(Class... paramaterTypes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29).

Comment: You seems like don't think. I meet the problem now. Construct with parameterTypes... So I need the specific type of reference object.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with a Constructor that you would need to do this. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and maybe you have a different question to ask. Something along the lines of "how do I do ____ with a Constructor?"

Answer (score 0):

You can go the java.lang.Class to access methods and then invoke them to get different information. If you want to know which class is based to instantiate an object, you could use referenceVariableName.getClass(); to get its super class, referenceVariableName.getClass().getSuperclass() to do that; to know interfaces, then you can use referenceVariableName.getClass().getInterfaces()[0] (the first interface since there are many interfaces maybe).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ObjectReferenceName {
   Interface a = new C();
   AbstractClass b = new C();
   C c =new C();
   static String getObjectReferenceName(String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException{
        return ObjectReferenceName.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName).getType().getName();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
       System.out.println(ObjectReferenceName.getObjectReferenceName("a"));
       System.out.println(ObjectReferenceName.getObjectReferenceName("b"));
       System.out.println(ObjectReferenceName.getObjectReferenceName("c"));
   }

}
```